# Pandas pivot but sum duplicate elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So, I have a dataset:

```
foo  bar  baz
---  ---  ---
one   A    1
one   B    2
one   B    3
two   A    4
two   B    5
two   C    6
```

I want to get such table:

```
foo  A  B  C
---  -  -  -
one  1  5  0
two  4  5  6
```

And by using:

```
df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')
```

I am getting such error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

How I can sum duplicate elements in pivot? Or maybe there is another command for such manipulations?

Comment: check `pivot_table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) instead:

```
>>> df.pivot_table("baz", "foo", "bar", "sum").fillna(0)

bar    A    B    C
foo               
one  1.0  5.0  0.0
two  4.0  5.0  6.0
```